# How to override apply and restore defaults

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to configure some appearance settings for a type of file. So I created a new entry in the `General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts`.

My `plugin.xml` looks like this:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.themes">
    <themeElementCategory
        id="com.example.themeElementCategory"
        label="My specific settings">
        <description>
            Control the appearance of .example files
        </description>
    </themeElementCategory>
    <colorDefinition
        categoryId="com.example.themeElementCategory"
        id="com.example.colorDefinition"
        label="Some Color"
        value="COLOR_DARK_BLUE">
        <description>
            Your description goes here
        </description>
    </colorDefinition>
    <fontDefinition
        categoryId="com.example.themeElementCategory"
        id="com.example.fontDefinition"
        label="Some Font"
        value="Lucida Sans-italic-18">
        <description>
            Description for this font
        </description>
    </fontDefinition>
</extension>
```

Now in the `Colors and Fonts` I have a new entry were I can set the color and the font.

How can I extend the preferences window so I can override the `Restore defaults`, `Apply` and `Apply and Close` buttons?

1. In my `<themeElementCategory>` I will have to add a `class=MyHandlingClass`which would override the `performApply()`, but what should that class extend/implement?
2. Same as 1, but add a `PropertyChangeEvent`, still don't know what should extend/implement
3. Less likely, create a new preference page which extends the `PreferencePage` and implements `IWorkbenchPreferencePage`

How can I achieve one of the first two options?

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION**
Currently the color and the font for a specific file extension are hardcoded in a class( I KNOW).
When the file is opened in the editor, the informations are read from that static class and visible in the editor.

What I wanted to do:

1. In a `static{}` block, read the settings configured in the preferences and update the static fields from my class.
2. If the user changes those settings from the preferences, on apply I wanted to update the static fields from the class and "repaint" the editor.

Comment: You can't override the buttons in the preference page. Why do you think you need to?

Comment: @greg-449 Oh, this is bad news... I updated the question with more informations why I want to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know when theme items change value use the `addPropertyChangeListener` method of `IThemeManager` to add a listener for changes:

```
IThemeManager manager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getThemeManager();

manager.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
```

The `PropertyChangeEvent` passed to the `propertyChanged` method of `IPropertyChangeListener` contains the id, old and new value of the changed theme item.